# Selecting the same SQL entry more than once from a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am working on a parts estimator program which pulls a list of parts from an SQL table into a drop-down menu. The selected entry's id is pushed into an array which is then used to show the data in the other columns for that id. for instance,a selection of a part from the drop-down menu would show its cost, hrs of labor, qty etc in a table. My question. Is there a simple way to allow for a user to select the same part twice and have it show up as a unique entry in my table?

My SQL SELECT statement right now is:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM upgrades WHERE part_id in ($id)";
```

$id is the array which contains the part_id(s) selected from the dropdown list. 
This will be much more simple than allowing the user to update the quantity of the part. Thank you for your time.

Here is my SQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE `otc_parts` (
`part_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`part_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`hours` double DEFAULT NULL,
`price` double DEFAULT NULL,
`other` double DEFAULT NULL,
`category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`parts` double DEFAULT NULL,
`labor_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`part_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4431 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is an example of some of my table data

```
Category            Part Name          Hrs        Qty          Price   Other

Misc        Portable 30A surge protector  0         1           289.95     0
```

Comment: `parts` and `part_selected_by_user` are different entitites and therefore there should be stored in different tables

Comment: Can you add an example of data (not table structure) and what exactly you want to get in the end?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to store the parts_selected_by_user in a separate table though. Just need to be able to print them. A more full fledged version of this program will have a login page and users being able to go to a separate page to reference their estimates but for now, they are just pulling parts from the database and printing them.

Comment: " It may look pushed together because there isn't any formatting in comment replies"  Then edit your question.